# How to encrypt/decrypt the database password with FME 2011?

Tags: fme-form

Is it possible to use the encryption MD5 or other for database password with FME 2011?
[Link](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36316/fme-spatial-etl/36902#36902)

Comment: md5 doesn't really _encrypt_ though, does it? Isn't that just a secure one-way hash?

Comment: No the value password is clear in FME SERVER request. I think that Python must have a library for the decryption of password.

Comment: @Chad: Why md5 doesn't really encrypt ?

Answer (score 2):

You can ENCODE the workspace itself.

Q) How secure is a password protected workspace?

A) We've taken efforts to make them as secure as possible to casual scrutiny. For example, there's no use anyone trying the FME_DEBUG keyword with the MAPPING_FILE option because we've made it invalid on protected content. I tried a number of ways to view a protected workspace in a text editor, or otherwise access the content, and couldn't.

However - we won't guarantee absolute security. We encode files, but we don't encrypt them; so it isn't like your local security agency of choice couldn't read them in ten seconds if you're thinking of creating a custom transformer such as 'DirtyMoneyLaunderer'!

As with all IT systems you can help security by...

```
Choosing a non-obvious password (ie not your name, your initials, your company name, "FME", "password", "pa$$word" etc)
Choosing a longer password (in general longer passwords are more secure)
```

source:
http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Password-Protection-for-FME-Workspaces

Comment: No the value password is clear in request If the public parameter has a crypted password, is it possible

Comment: The password is clear in FME Server request so is it possible to crypted the password before the translation with FME ? If yes, how to make ?